# Is there a way to get all tables/views used to make a view? (Including parents and "grandparents")

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2019

Some `VIEW`s are joins of multiple views and tables, which in turn were joined from other views and tables, and so on.

The rabbit holes appear deep from looking into them manually. (Following the thread of all the joins by pulling up the view creation scripts, one after another, after another, after another...you get the idea.)

Some of our queries are taking the approximate speed of paint drying. I was hoping there was a way to quickly call up the "family trees" of some of our more problematic views to get a full picture of their "ancestry."

Is there a system function, stored procedure, query, or other functionality in SSMS that will give me a list (or diagram, if it's a SSMS built-in functionality) of all "parents"/"grandparents"/"great-grandparents"/etc. of a view? (Or a table for that matter?)

I did a fairly exhaustive Google search (and searched here on SO and similar sites) for a solution, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. I think one issue is that I don't know the proper terminology (e.g., I don't think "parents" and "grandparents" are the right words here).

If there are more proper terms for the functionality/objects that I am talking about, I would appreciate any corrections.

Comment: [`sp_depends`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) might give you what you're looking for.

Comment: It sounds like you might be nesting `VIEW`s; these rarely perform well. You might want to try "unnested" them and see what performance is like.

Comment: @Larnu I would love that, but unfortunately, I don't have any control over the way the db was already set up, and many people use these views other than myself so I can't change them.

Comment: @TZHX Thanks much for your suggestion! I could be wrong, but I think that only gives the object's dependencies, not what it depends on.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is dependency.

Comment: Try this article:  https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-tables-used-by-a-view

Comment: Here's another on creating dependency diagrams: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-a-sql-dependency-diagram-in-sql-server/